# How will trophies work if I play Borderlands 2 on PS Vita after playing it on the PS3?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2, ps3, ps-vita

Let's say that I have earned 100% of the trophies in *Borderlands 2* on the PS3. If I were to play the PS Vita version, would it register as a new *game* on my PSN, therefore allowing me to earn all the trophies again? Or rather, would it *stack* on top of my existing trophies?

And in the same line of question: Would it be possible to transfer the save files of my game from the PS3 to the PS Vita? That is, if thy use the same file format.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that trophy implementation for cross-save games are implementation dependent. Sometimes it's the same trophy list, sometimes it's not and sometimes earning a trophy in one save then loading a cross-save awards you a trophy and sometimes not. So this game's implementation could be different from others'.

Comment: In line with what @BenBrocka said, I'll add the game-specific tag to this, because it really does depend. Or not, since it seems like my browser is acting up and won't let me save changes. Whatever.

Comment: I believe it depends on how the game is marketed.  For instance, with "Fez", you buy it once, you get it on PS3/PS4/Vita and all versions share trophies.  For Borderlands, the Vita version is sold differently, and so it is considered a "different" game.  It's the game code itself that awards the actual trophies, so the publisher would control if you get trophies from saves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transferring the save game can be done with a [recent update to the PS3 version](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/ps-vita-borderlands-2-adding-cross-save-feature-next-week/1100-6419709/).

For the trophies there are two separate lists, but if you transfer a save from the PS3 which has acquired trophies it will unlock them on the Vita, and vice versa. So, you *can* go through unlocking them all again if you want to, or you can transfer a save from your old game to unlock ones you've already acquired.

Comment: So let's say the PS3 version have 50 trophies, I can win 50 free trophies just by transfering my save file to the Vita? That would be amazing!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté That's how it seems to be working, yes.

Comment: @TZHX This is exactly what happens with Motorstorm RC, I got two Platinums for the price of one.

Answer (score 0):

No, PS3 and Vita have the same trophy list. There is cross save between PS3 and vita for Borderlands 2.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It depends on the developer.  Some games share trophies, some do not.

Comment: They may have the same trophy list (available trophies and unlock conditions), but it appears twice in the 'Games' when you look at your PSN / trohpies app.

Answer (score -2):

You will not re-earn trophies.